# Receiving from ActiveMQ Artemis with artemis-jms-client throws InvalidDestinationException

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have this in my code

```
consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue("myQueue"));
```

It throws the following exception

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: AMQ119019: Queue already exists test_simple_transaction_receiver
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:406)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.createQueue(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:546)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.internalCreateQueue(ClientSessionImpl.java:1622)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.createQueue(ClientSessionImpl.java:249)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:628)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:331)
        at consumeMessage(ReceiverClient.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artemis 2.0.0 has a new addressing model. if you need backward compatibility you have to configure the acceptors in such way the older clients would connect.

So, I would recommend just updating your client.

Answer (score 1):

I used a wrong version of `artemis-jms-client`. My broker is Artemis 2.0.0 and I used `artemis-jms-client` 1.5.3.

With a matching client library version, the receiving works.

I made this mistake once already, so I am posting about it here in case it helps somebody else, or me third time still.